# Sendmail From address

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp-headers

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to use sendmail to send a message with a custom "from" e-mail address.  The body of the message is a file, pasted below.

What I'm seeing is that when I specify a "From:" address, the e-mail doesn't get sent at all.  When I specify a "Reply-To" the reply-to address is ignored, and when I send using both a "From" and a "Reply-To", the message doesn't get sent.

The SMTP file used in the e-mail is pasted below.  Again, thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

```
SUBJECT: Testreplytofrom
From: <accounting@company.com>
Reply-To: <accounting@company.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="FILEBOUNDARY"

--FILEBOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Disposition: inline

TEST MESSAGE
--FILEBOUNDARY
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: @DanP Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

1/ Remove "From" and "Reply-To" lines from your template email

2/ cat template.email | sendmail -f "accounting@company.com"

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use **[`smtp-cli`](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli/)** to send your email:

```
$ smtp-cli --verbose --server localhost --subject ... \
           --from accounting@company.com --to ...@... \
           --body-plain /path/to/the/file.txt
```

Refer to the *[smtp-cli page](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/smtp-cli/)* for more usage examples.